# USB packet capture with Java

Tags: java, usb, packet

So I have USBpcap and can live capture packets from my USB mouse using wireshark and now I want to write a program to interpret these packets. I really want something similar to Jnetpcap so that I can process the USB data from my mouse.

Does anyone know where to start with this? My goal would be to have a program that can tell you when you click the mouse, and when you move right and left and so on. From using wireshark with USBpcap I know what each of these packets looks like so the bit I need some help with is finding a way to read the packets using java as they come in through the USB port.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible using just java. You would need to use some other language to get data from the USB port, and then use JNI (Java Native Interface) to get the data to Java.

You could use C# instead (which is very similar to Java) using something like [USB Event Tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/JJ151577(v=VS.85).aspx).

Another alternative you could use is to just monitor *the mouse* instead of the USB data. This would have the added advantage that mice using different drivers would still work with your program, not to mention that it would be way less work on your part. [Here's a tutorial](http://kra.lc/blog/2011/07/java-global-system-hook/) on how to use C++ to capture mouse events and then send them to Java over JNI.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into C# using USB Event Tracing. I like your idea to capture mouse movements but the reason I want to do this is practice for capturing and interpreting data from a more complicated USB device.

Comment: Then your best bet is definitely to use C# or C++. Java just isn't cut out for this type of thing because of its cross platform nature.